# Can't install ArcGIS License Manager 10.1 on Win Server 2003

Tags: arcgis-10.1, installation, server, license, arcgis-license-manager

i try to install a License Manager on a Windows 2003 Server.

The setup starts, everything looks fine. When i press "next" the setup crashes, the setup window closes. No error. No entry in the event viewer...

I already tried to create a installation log.

> "C:\MyPackage\Setup.exe" /L*V "example.log"

But nothing is created...

Whats the problem? :/

Comment: are you doing right-click 'run as administrator'? for the setup

Comment: Yes, im also logged in as administrator. Tried it via command-line...

Comment: Is the Windows Server 2003 on SP2? it is a minimum requirement for ArcGIS 10.1 http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.1/index.html#//015100000002000000

Comment: 2003 R2 Standard Edition Service Pack 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled the windows installer. It's working now.